# Is this a good enough P-Trap

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, p-trap

This is the plumbing under our bathtub.  We are getting strong sewer gas odors in the bathroom above this plumbing.  Sometimes I can smell it coming from the tub and sometimes not.  Is there a chance gases are coming through the tub plumbing because this isn’t a good enough P-Trap?  An odd addition to this is, we live in Minnesota and the smell seems more frequent when the weather starts getting colder in the fall through the winter and can be smelled outside sometimes too.  I’m not sure if that has anything to do with our problem but I figured I’d add it in..[image]

Comment: "Good enough" could mean many things, and obviously there are issues here but from the pure perspective of whether this "trap" would effectively act as a trap , there is nothing obvious in the photo that would make it fail but depending on what happens further down that pipe on the right side, you may have a siphon problem.

Comment: If the smell is also noticeable on the outside I would suspect that the drainage line does not have proper vents at the appropriate locations.  Without proper vents, water draining through the pipes can cause siphoning effects that empty the P-traps and allow the sewer gases to pass through the basin drains.

Comment: jay613, the pipe on the right of the photo goes to the sewer main.  There’s about 5 feet between that trap and the main.

Comment: Also, would adding an air admittance valve possibly help if I’ve got a syphoning issue?

Comment: If that is a 5' run then you would most definitely need to add an air admittance valve.  In general, "If the waste line has a diameter of 1 1/4 inches, the vent can be no farther than 2 1/2 feet from the trap. If the waste line is 1 1/2 inches, this critical distance is 3 1/2 feet.".  This would be for all drains in your house.

Comment: Thank you very much for that info Programmer66.  That was very helpful.